# Android 9 double web view instance

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, webview, angular10

I am running on Android 9 web view and after 20 hours the web view doubles itself. I am running Project Angular 10.2.5 by Ionic Cordova
Has anyone encountered this type of problem?

[image]